# сравнение данных из одного датафрейма в с данными в другом

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть две таблицы:

table1

| номер |
| --- |
| 2877348604945 |
| 2654787454945 |
| 2877325684945 |
| 1568565685656 |
| 5623565432565 |

table2

| номер |
| --- |
| 2877348123587 |
| 2654722121211 |
| 2877325620121 |
| 1568561212121 |
| 5623565232323 |

Результат
table 3

номер_t2 - данные из таблицы 2

префикс - сравниваются номера из таблицы 2 с номерами из таблицы 1 слева направо.
Равна той части которая совпадает + 1 символ

н/р:
2877348123587 сравнивается с 2877348604945. Результат 28773481.

| номер_t2 | префикс |
| --- | --- |
| 2877348123587 | 28773481 |
| 2654722121211 | 265472 |
| 2877325620121 | 287732562 |
| 1568565685656 | 1568565 |
| 5623565232323 | 56235652 |

Comment: сравнение строго построчно? может ли не быть совпадений?

Answer (score 2):

Если сравнение идет строго построчно, то можно сделать так, например:

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
# исходные данные
l1 = ["2877348604945", "2654787454945", "2877325684945", "1568565685656", "5623565432565"]
l2 = ["2877348123587", "2654722121211", "2877325620121", "1568561212121", "5623565232323"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=["номер1"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=["номер2"])
# объединяем в один датафрейм:
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

def get_last_match(a):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a["номер1"], a["номер2"]).find_longest_match().size+1

df["префикс"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["номер2"][:get_last_match(x)], axis=1)
```

df:

```text
          номер1         номер2    префикс
0  2877348604945  2877348123587   28773481
1  2654787454945  2654722121211     265472
2  2877325684945  2877325620121  287732562
3  1568565685656  1568561212121    1568561
4  5623565432565  5623565232323   56235652
```

Comment: Очевидно, что код не быстрый, раз речь идет о простом переборе. однако имплементация префиксного дерева для сравнения "строка в строку" вряд ли сделает код эффективнее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а почему именно trie, можно же просто за счет векторизации ускорить. Я просто не профи, может я не знаю каких то подводных камней векторизации помимо больших бесполезных выделениях памяти?

Comment: @Step1709, я решал другую задачу, в которой каждую строку первого фрейма сравнивал с каждой строкой второго. Вы правы, векторизация решает. Трие не нужен.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy бывает, я тоже не сразу условие вопроса правильно понял)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, на сколько этот способ эффективен при большом объеме данных, но по скорости по идее должен быть быстрее `apply()`, за счет векторизации:

```
def prefer(x, y):
    if str(y) == 'nan':
        return 0
    else:
        s = 1
        for i in range(0, len(str(y))):
            if str(y)[i]==str(x)[i]:
                s +=1
            else:
                break
        return int(str(y)[0:s])

df['prefix'] = np.vectorize(prefer)(df['номер1'], df['номер2'])
```

ПС. я не знаю в каком формате данные в таблице int или str, но столбец prefix будет в формате int, если надо поменять, то напишите)

ПС2. проверил на 5млн строк-где то за 25 сек выполняется

Comment: а если в первой таблице данных больше чем во второй

Comment: @AizhanAskhatova тогда будет выдавать ошибку скорее всего, но в вопросе не было сказано про разные размеры просто, да и по логике, если второй столбец пустой, то префикс поидее тоже отсутствует, можно поменять функцию немного, добавив в начале условие, сейчас добавлю его в ответ

Comment: @AizhanAskhatova добавил в ответ проверку, которая, если в столбце 2 пусто будет выводить в префикс 0, можно 0 заменить на None или любое другое значение, которое нужно